# Pandas: Sum over time range considering max value of different entities

Tags: pandas, date, sum, time-series, pandas-groupby

```
date        value           pointName   pointNr     connectedPoint  ownerName
2018-05-08  2.039373e+08    Miami_1     P-00068     Point_1         Owner_1
2018-05-09  2.546125e+08    Miami_1     P-00068     Point_1         Owner_1 
2018-05-09  2.546010e+08    Miami_2     P-00066     Point_1         Owner_2 
2018-05-08  2.037412e+08    Miami_2     P-00066     Point_1         Owner_2 
2018-05-09  7.142878e+08    New_York_1  P-00211     Point_2         Owner_3 
2018-05-08  6.567392e+08    New_York_1  P-00211     Point_2         Owner_3 
2018-05-08  6.567392e+08    New_York_2  P-00188     Point_2         Owner_4 
2018-05-09  7.141274e+08    New_York_3  P-00126     Point_2         Owner_2 
2018-05-09  7.142878e+08    New_York_2  P-00188     Point_2         Owner_4 
2018-05-08  6.566841e+08    New_York_3  P-00126     Point_2         Owner_2 
2018-05-08  0.000000e+00    Boston_1    P-00081     Point_3         Owner_4 
2018-05-08  0.000000e+00    Boston_2    P-00105     Point_3         Owner_5
2018-05-09  6.987462e+07    Boston_2    P-00105     Point_3         Owner_5
2018-05-09  7.000680e+07    Boston_1    P-00081     Point_3         Owner_4
```

The snippet above is more or less the outcome of:

```
rng = pd.DataFrame(my_df[['date', 'value', 'pointName', 'pointNr', 'connectedPoint', 'ownerName]].sort_values('connectedPoint').reset_index(drop=True))
rng.head(14)
```

I got the data over the whole year. For this example i picked two days (2018-05-08 and 2018-05-09)

I’d like to calculate the sum over a timerange (here in this case: two days), but for each day just counting the maximum value of each connectedPoint.

An example for 2018-05-08 in pseudo mathematical writing:
 
sum(max{Point1} + max{Point2} + max{Point3})
= 2.039373e+08 + 6.567392e+08 + …

Finally we sum up the values (meaning the before calculated sums) for each day (day1 + day2 + day3…) resulting in one final value.

I tried different approachs with groupby, as well as variations of:

```
rng['date'] = pd.to_datetime(rng['date'])
rng.index = rng['date'] 
rng.resample('D').max()
```

Sorry, I’m new to python and pandas. I searched online, but still I can't find a solution even this case here is obvious for many of you. I’m stuck.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: please,copy and paste your df

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [DataFrame.groupby](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) + [DataFrame.unstack](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html)

```
df1=df.groupby(['date','connectedPoint'])['value'].max().unstack()
print(df1)
```

---

```
connectedPoint      Point_1      Point_2     Point_3
date                                                
2018-05-08      203937300.0  656739200.0         0.0
2018-05-09      254612500.0  714287800.0  70006800.0
```

---

**Getting total sum by date:**

```
sum_date=df1.sum(axis=1)
print(sum_date)

date
2018-05-08    8.606765e+08
2018-05-09    1.038907e+09
dtype: float64
```

---

**Getting total sum:**

```
sum_tot=sum_date.sum()
print(sum_tot)

1899583600.0
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I tried it, and it worked. Didn't know unstack(). There's a lot to read and discover ;)

Comment: I am glad to help :)